# How to change the external content type of a list?

Tags: list, external-content-type, external-data

I have a webpart that consumes and displays items from a list that has an external content type.

The problem is that the list is consuming the wrong font and I would like to know

If it is possible to change the external data source of the list and how it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the current `External Content Type data source`, by doing the following:

- Open SharePoint Designer.
- From the left side > click on the External Content Type.
- Right-click your External Content Type > Select `Edit External Content Type`

[image]

- From the above ribbon, Click on `Operation View`.
- Click on `Add connection` button to add a new data source.
- Or `Edit Operation` to edit the current External Content Type operations.
- Or `Remove Operation`, to delete the selected External Content Type operations.

[image]

Comment: It was EXACTLY what I needed.
Thank you very much.